# Clicking between columns to fix the size, eliminates my size settings - the WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I defined in the DataGrid the size of the columns in the following way:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding X}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*">
```

This works **fine** until the moment **I press between the two columns** to see the entire contents of a particular column, then he does not know my definition of this column and increases the column more than necessary **by its contents.**

Why is this happening and How can prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent this by using style from this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248.aspx and remove from that: `PART_LeftHeaderGripper` and `PART_RightHeaderGripper`.

```
<Window.Resources>
...
<!--Style and template for the DataGridColumnHeader.-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="columnHeaderBorder"
  BorderThickness="1"
  Padding="3,0,3,0">
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                   StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
              Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
              Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.BorderBrush>
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                   StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
              Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
              Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>

            <!--<Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper"
 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
 Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />-->
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Background">
<Setter.Value>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
           StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
      Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
      Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
...
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: You must copy styles from microsoft site (link to this site you find in my answer) and you must find style for `DataGridColumnHeader` and replace it with mine.